# UIMenuController with a set of colored button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a requirement - in an application i'm currently developing - to show a list of colors upon clicking on a button so the user can select a single color out of the list. I strongly believe the best way to this would be to have a UIMenuController popup - just like you'd see the copy/cut/paste menu in iphone - and show the list of colors in that menu. However I do not wish to show the color names in the menu, instead I would love to have the buttons colored. But I'm still unable to see a way to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I had the same requirement and did't find any possibility to change the menu items. The only solution I found, was to create a custom popover looking like this menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closet thing i have found to do this is a custom popover that allows customization of colors called `JSMenuController`. It is open-source and can be found here:

http://jernejstrasner.com/iphone-classes/

The only downside is that as far as I can tell, all the buttons must have the same color, although this can be any color of your choice. But possibly with a look inside their code you might be able to modify it to have different colors for each button.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. This is definitely a good starting point. I went through the code and pretty confident if I spent several hours, I can get it to have different colors for each button. But still, i'm lazy :D.. Still looking for a shortcut :)

Comment: Looks like he has removed it from his site. Fortunately i saved a copy for myself, here it is: http://idzr.org/tuz1